# How to make the redux-saga values display on the screen [NextJS Redux-Saga]

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, next.js

Using in NextJS, I'm having trouble configuring the Redux Saga using the example available in NextJS github.

I put the code in the sandbox for anyone who can help me.

https://codesandbox.io/s/next-woi1k

The information I need is on the redux_clock.js page at the URL:

https://woi1k.sse.codesandbox.io/redux_clock

If I get the redux-saga information in ComponentDidMount, I can display the redux-saga values on the screen, but if I search for the correct NextJS information in getInitialProps, it is not being displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem.

It was missing to put the initial state of the new reducer.